# Spyder console not displaying function output

Tags: python, console, spyder, built-in

I'm new to coding, and as I was going through a beginner's Python walkthrough, I found that the console in Spyder won't give an output that states the class type of the argument.

Image after running type () in Spyder:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to use a `print` if you want to see something printed in the console. In the example shown above, you need to change your code like this

```
print(type(13.4))
```

to see the result displayed in the console.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!